# Field validation not working correctly

Tags: validation

We are on Sitecore 8.2 and just upgraded to update 7 from update 2 and we are now experiencing issues with field validation. When a user goes to approve or publish an item after making changes they get "You cannot approve an item with validation errors." But the field(s) in question do have valid data. And furthermore, if you go to the review tab and click on the validation button, everything comes back green (all fields with validation are fine).

We have no custom validators on the items that are having issues. And if an admin goes in and changes the workflow state to approved and publishes it works as expected.

Comment: Can you check whether some Validation Rules in Gutter is causing this? See this article where to find Gutter. Just right click on left side and check "Validation Rules". http://drexel.edu/cms/getting-started/configure/gutter/

Comment: Yes, all validation rules on all fields are the same.  We are just applying the required validation to the fields in question.

Comment: I was just wondering that maybe different field is causing you this trouble in Gutter. Try it please as Gutter can have different Validation Rules

Comment: Like I said, all that do show up are warnings with that on.  There are no errors that show up because all the fields have data (that are required).

Comment: Did you get any answer, I am facing same issue. We did not upgrade just installed sitecore 9 and created a simple template with one field and added required field valdator and getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to put in a support ticket with sitecore.  It turned out this was an issue in the sitecore.kernel.dll itself.  They created a patch file for us that fixed the issue [here](https://sitecore.box.com/s/hp1uvqy2k6cmhtheb5j4kn6qcpf3c2ls)